# How find @username in string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How to find `@username` in given string using javascript and regex and move them to a div ?

Allowed Items:

```
@username
@user_name
```

Not Allowed Items:

```
@_username // non alphabetical character at the beginning
@1username // a number at the beginning
@username_ // underscore at the end
```

I want to wrap them in a div.
What i tried: https://regex101.com/r/olqjsv/2

Comment: put a `\b` at the end https://regex101.com/r/dmxyK6/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution using [***String.prototype.replace()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function with specific regex pattern:

```js
var str = "@username  @username_   @user_name @1username",
    result = str.replace(/@[a-z]\w+[a-z]\b/gi, "<div>$&</div>");

console.log(result);
```

`$&` - special replacement pattern, points to the matched substring

Answer (score -1):

try tihs

```
(\@username|\@user_name)|\@([a-zA-Z]+)\_\@([a-zA-Z]+)
```